# How to join multiple tables and GROUP BY in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, group-by

I am trying to collect all of the sessions (one row each) for a user and then group the rows by date so that the data can be sorted on the front end of my application.

I am able to SELECT and JOIN the columns from four different tables, but I cannot figure out how to now use GROUP BY on the output.

This works:

```
SELECT session_streams.app_id, session_streams.start_time, session_streams.scenario_fk, session_streams.session_fk, session_streams.stream_fk, scenarios.scenario_name, streams.stream_name
FROM session_streams
JOIN scenarios
ON session_streams.scenario_fk = scenarios.id
JOIN streams
ON session_streams.stream_fk = streams.id
JOIN users
ON users.app_id = session_streams.app_id
WHERE users.email = '{email}'
ORDER BY session_streams.start_time DESC
```

This results in an error:

```
SELECT session_streams.app_id, session_streams.start_time, session_streams.scenario_fk, session_streams.session_fk, session_streams.stream_fk, scenarios.scenario_name, streams.stream_name
FROM session_streams
JOIN scenarios
ON session_streams.scenario_fk = scenarios.id
JOIN streams
ON session_streams.stream_fk = streams.id
JOIN users
ON users.app_id = session_streams.app_id
WHERE users.email = '{email}'
GROUP BY session_streams.start_time
ORDER BY session_streams.start_time DESC
```

> Error: "column "session_streams.app_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"

When I add the "required" column to the GROUP BY clause, it asks for the next column listed in the SELECT clause. Adding all of those columns in the SELECT clause does not yield a different result.

How can I GROUP BY only one column on this output?

Comment: you need to provide sample data and desired output and an explanation on what you are trying to do

Comment: The answer is: you can't. In a `GROUP BY` query (well, except in MySQL) , each expression in the SELECT list is either one that reappears in the `GROUP BY` clause, or it is an aggregate function: `MIN()`,`MAX()`,`AVG()`,`SUM()`,`COUNT()`, just to list the usually most popular ones.

Answer (score 0):

In the question, you should clarify your intent.  The SQL does not clearly indicate the intent.  Having said that, review this ...

Just be careful you understand what this does and how the `ORDER BY` impacts which rows end up in the result. You can use `DISTINCT ON` in postgresql, like this.

It's possible you'll want to add logic to the `ORDER BY` to determine which row within each group is in the result.  It's hard to know without more detail in the question.

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8ee35c32364f4db3cd80e48bb01474d9)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (session_streams.start_time)
       session_streams.app_id
     , session_streams.start_time
     , session_streams.scenario_fk
     , session_streams.session_fk
     , session_streams.stream_fk
     , scenarios.scenario_name
     , streams.stream_name
  FROM session_streams
  JOIN scenarios
    ON session_streams.scenario_fk = scenarios.id
  JOIN streams
    ON session_streams.stream_fk = streams.id
  JOIN users
    ON users.app_id = session_streams.app_id
 WHERE users.email = '{email}'
 ORDER BY session_streams.start_time DESC
;
```